Where exactly are we using the fact that $f$ is an odd function in the proof of the Borsuk-Ulam Theorem?
Consider the proposition that $f:S^n \to S^n$ is an odd map implies $f$ has an odd degree, which is essentially the proposition used in Borsuk-Ulam theorem's proof as given in Hatcher. Now one point which I recently noticed while giving a talk is the following:
When $f$ is odd i.e. $f(-x)=-f(x)$, we can induce a map $\overline f:\mathbb RP^n\to \mathbb RP^n$ in the quotient level such that $\overline f([x])=[f(x)]$ i.e. $\overline f\circ p=p\circ f$ where $p:S^n\to \mathbb RP^n$ is the quotient map. But observe that even when $f$ is an even map, then $f(-x)=f(x)$ and then also we can induce the map $\overline f:\mathbb RP^n\to \mathbb RP^n$ such that $\overline f\circ p=p\circ f$. So, the proof essentially should follow in the same way. But it does not.
Where exactly are we using the fact that $f$ is odd map? I am still not able to see it very clearly. What am I overlooking exactly?

(1) When we have ODD function , then we have $f(-x)=-f(x)$ , where we have $f(-0)=-f(0)$ , hence $f(0)=0$ (2) We do not get that with EVEN function , hence we can not claim that $f(0)=0$ (3) You should give Details of the references & write out the ODD Proof , which we can check ( the Document by Hatcher which I have is not containing the Proof you gave here ) (4) When you give that Proof , you should also write out the EVEN Proof. We can check to see where that went wrong

@Prem In the proof of the proposition used in Hatcher to prove Borsuk Ulam theorem.We have one commutative square $f_{\sharp} \tau=\tau \overline f_{\sharp}$,and If I am not wrong,what you are saying is that for $0$ simplex also it is supposed to be true that $f\circ \tau(0)=\tau\circ \overline f(0)$,which comes from the fact that $f(-0)=-f(0)$ which is a result of the fact that $f$ is odd.Now my question remains,what if we remove the assumption that $f$ is odd and instead replace it with the assumption that $f(0)=0$.

@Prem What happens if $f$ is an even function satisfying $f(0)=0$?

@KishalaySarkar As Prem mentionned, you should edit your post and attempt to write out the proof for even functions and either get stuck at some point where you need that the function is odd or don't get stuck and then we can help by pointing out your mistakes. It makes sure that everybody knows exactly what you mean and people don't have to guess what proof you are talking about.

Why do you keep making comments about $f(0)$ when $0$ is not even in the domain of $f$?

Hatcher uses the fact that an odd function $f:\mathbb{S}^n\to\mathbb{S}^n$ maps antipodal points to antipodal points, i.e. given a point $a\in\mathbb{S}^n$, $f$ sends $a$ and $-a$ to $f(a)$ and $-f(a)=f(-a)$, respectively. However, this is clearly not true for even maps.
Furhtermore, a similar result holds for even maps. See this post Show that $\deg f$ is even when $n$ is odd..

You probably did not get my point.I want to know the exact step where this is required in the proof.

It is used in order to verify the commutativity of the left-hand square of the diagram at the bottom of page 175.

But I did not understand what would have been the problem otherwise with the two lifts of $\overline f\circ \simga$ also in Hatcher,they have not mentioned it in detail,I precisely want an explanantion of that part.
